# Custom Configuration Section Handler throwing an exception

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am getting the following error:

```
"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for Config/Site1:
Could not load file or assembly Operations or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified. (....vshost.exe.config line 9)
```

Can any one help?

Here is my app.config file if it helps:

```
...
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="Config">
    <section name="Sites" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
    <section name="Site1" type="Operations.Site1SectionHandler, Operations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" 
    allowLocation="true" 
    allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
...
<Config>
  <Sites Site1="mySite1" />
  <Site1
    Property1="Value1"
  />
</Config>
...
```

And here is my declared Site1SectionHandler (project default namespace is Operations):

```
Class Site1SectionHandler
  Inherits ConfigurationSection

  <ConfigurationProperty("Property1", IsRequired:=True)> _
  Public ReadOnly Property Property1 As String
    Get
        Return Me("Property1")
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

And this is how I call it and where the exeption occurs:

```
Dim mySite1 = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Config/Site1")
```

Do not know if I am missing the obvious.
I originally tried without the Version/Culture/... etc stuff but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Apologise if I waisted anyone's time, my mistake so you can close this one. I searched for an answer on google, cannot remember what site it was but something triggered my mind to realise my executible name and thus my assembly name was not the same as my default namespace. So I changed:

```
<section name="Site1" type="Operations.Site1SectionHandler, Operations" />
```

to

```
<section name="Site1" type="Operations.Site1SectionHandler, OperationsProcessing" />
```

i.e. my exe name was OperationsProcessing.exe